# Using Maven to Deploy on Embedded Tomcat with a Datasource

Tags: maven-2, tomcat, datasource, embeddedwebserver

I have a multi module maven web application, which uses hibernate.

I use the tomcat:run goal in order to run it on the embedded tomcat server of maven. Everything works fine so far.

But now I need to switch from an explicite jdbc configuration in the hibernate.properties to a datasource. I did the following:

- changed hibernate.properties

from

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:somejdbcurl
hibernate.connection.username=aUser
hibernate.connection.password=aPassword
```

to

```
hibernate.connection.datasource=java:comp/env/jdbc/datasourcename
```

- in web.xml I added

> ```
> <resource-ref>
>     <res-ref-name>jdbc/datasourcename</res-ref-name>
>     <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
>     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
> </resource-ref>
> ```

- added a context.xml next to the web.xml with the following content:

> ```
> <Context>
>   <Resource name="jdbc/datasourcename"
>          auth="Container"
>          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
>          username="aUser" password="aPassword"
>          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
>          url="jdbc:somejdbcurl"
>          maxActive="2" maxIdle="2"/>
> </Context>
> ```

This doesn't work, which is expected, since I didn't find a way to provide the jar file, containing the Oracle jdbc driver. I expected a ClassNotFound Exception or something similar, but instead I got a

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
```

with a root cause down in the stack:

```
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
```

Soooooo the questions are:

- Why doesn't tomcat know that I want it to use the Oracle Driver?
- How do I tell the tomcat about the jar file which contains the driver?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the JDBC driver inside the plugin declaration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <configuration>
    ...
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>...</groupId>
      <artifactId>...</artifactId>
      <version>...</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

By the way, the default value for the [`contextFile`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#contextFile) is `src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml`.

Comment: that looks promising, I'll try that tomorrow

Comment: thanks for pointing out the default contextFile location.. i spent a few hours chasing that ..